# UNION clause in embedded SQL

Tags: sql, ingres

I'm using ingres 10S SQL, and I'm trying to write the following SQL statement in an embedded SQL C program.  It works fine as a standalone SQL script, but compiling the eSQL program gets the error

> `%% Error in file localtask.sc, Line 498:
>   E_EQ0244 Syntax error on 'union'.`

```
INSERT INTO nr301_tab2 (authority_id)
SELECT a.authority_id
FROM nrremdets a, nrstatus_hierarchy z
WHERE a.authority_id = z.authority_id
UNION
SELECT a.authority_id
FROM nrsumsamts a, nrsumsdets b
WHERE a.authority_id = b.authority_id;
```

(line 498 is the `UNION` line) What's wrong with that `UNION` clause?

Comment: You can't do a union when doing a insert query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a slight tweak of the query and it should work. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO nr301_tab2 (authority_id)
SELECT authority_id
FROM
    (SELECT a.authority_id
     FROM nrremdets a, nrstatus_hierarchy z
     WHERE a.authority_id = z.authority_id
     UNION
     SELECT a.authority_id
     FROM nrsumsamts a, nrsumsdets b
     WHERE a.authority_id = b.authority_id) Result
```

The idea is to union the result sets, which will create a new result set to be inserted once in the table. By adding the parenthesis we make sure that this happens.

Comment: What does `Result` signify in that snippet?  I now get a syntax error on that, but it compiles fine if I remove it.

Comment: Ok, then remove it. I don't have experience with `Ingres` so I wasn't sure if  it would be required or not, but most RDBMS systems require you to add a name for the result set generated by a `UNION`, if you want to reference the entire result set in the higher level of the query.

Comment: Have you run it yet rojomoke? I was able to compile without a correlation name, such as result, but got a runtime error. With one it compiles and runs OK. I tested on latest 10S so might be worth checking your patch level.

Comment: @PaulM So, it would be corect to leave the ‘Result‘ alias for the result set, at the end of the query? Like I mentioned before, I don't have experience with Ingres.

Comment: For me it fails with a syntax error if a correlation name is supplied, but compiles fine without one.  I'll let you know whether it runs tomorrow.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu yes not only is it correct but according to the Ingres SQL Guide it should be required.

Comment: @PaulM Ok, thanks for the update. I modified my answer since I also consider it to be correct. Maybe it depends on the IDE the OP is using?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu, @PaulM I finally got around to running this, and yes, with `Result` at the end, it fails with a syntax error.  However, it turns out that RESULT is a reserved word.  Replace it with 'myResult', and it's fine.